# Distance between broken line and experimental values

Tags: matlab, data-fitting

I need to evaluate a set of broken lines (red line), returned by a forward model, and select the one best fitting a set of experimental values (green dots); example in the image below. Do you have any suggestion on how to calculate the distance of the points from the broken line?

[image]

Comment: Do you have access to the curve-fitting toolbox? https://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/curve-fitting.html

Comment: Yes! But I don't have to fit the points distribution... What I need to do is to find, among the fits returned by a forward model, the one whose point distribution (red line) best fits the experimental values

Comment: Do points (stars) match 1 to 1?

Comment: Nope. The number of experimental and calculated values is not related.

Comment: How is the line described in MATLAB? Is it just the red points? do you have a function? I.e. How would you know the value of the red line between 2 "stars" ?

Comment: If the model is returning a function, I would recommend looking into `fminsearch` or `fmincon` to calculate the distance from each point.  If the model is described as a vector of points, you can estimate this by finding the euclidean distance from each point to each other point, and taking the min value.  Then, look into "root mean squared (RMS)" difference measures to summarize the fit - or essentially equivalently, @AnderBiguri's suggestion

Comment: @tmpearce as points are not 1 to 1 equivalent, a plain RMS will not work.

Comment: @AnderBiguri It will once the nearest point from each green point is found (as in the first half of my comment)

Comment: @tmpearce No it wont. In a general scenario, where the distances among green points differ from distances among red points (sample rate, or whatever) that will not work. Even in the case where its the same, if all green points lie exactly in the middle of the red points, a desired score would give 100%, or 0, or "this is the best possible case". An RMS to the closes point (as you propose) will not give that, and will give a hihger value than 15 green poitns next to 1 red point, which would be a worse scenario

Comment: @AnderBiguri If I'm understanding right, you're concerned that if a green point lies on the line between two red points, the distance should be zero but would be interpreted by a simple algorithm as non-zero.  That's true... but if the red line is actually a function, this is irrelevant because a true distance can be computed, and if not, it is essentially solved by interpolation (with more points, the estimate gets closer to "reality").  The point is, once you're interpolating, you already are making an estimate of the distance, so it won't ever actually be perfect or "true".

Comment: @tmpearce If the red line is a function is irrelevant, I agree. I doubt it is, because of the information given by OP. If not, a better approximation than the one you proposed could be interpolating more samples yes. However, considering scientific rigor, the less approximate the method the better. However, I insist, just RMSing will not work, not because approximation, but because worse cases will get better scores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A decent (I think) approach would be to compute the sum of square distances from the fit to the points.

Assuming that you describe the links between the red dots as straight lines, then you can do it by

1. Computing the equation of each line between red points.
2. Compute distances between green points and red points. Assign the line from (1.) between closest 2 red points to each green dot.
3. [Compute distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line) between each green dot and corresponding (2.) line.
4. `score=sum(sqrt(distances))`

If you want interpolate between your red points with something other than linear you may need to find a bit fancier maths, but the process should be the same.

Comment: I essentially agree - use the method of interpolation most appropriate for your model, find the nearest distance from each green point, and aggregate those distances somehow.